# Override ChoiceField widget in Django ModelForm without re-specifying choices

Tags: django, django-forms, django-models

I am trying to override the default widget for a Django `ChoiceField` while preserving the choices generated in the model.  Here is the relevant part of my model:

```
class UserGroup(models.Model):
    icon = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=<function call>)
```

And of my form:

```
class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    icon = models.ChoiceField(widget=IconPicker)

    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = [ 'icon', ]
```

Overriding the `ChoiceField`'s widget like this clobbers the `form.fields['icon'].choices` attribute normally inherited from the model and sets it to `[]` because Django.  If I remove the `icon` field definition from the form, the choices are preserved - but of course the widget defaults to a `Select`.

(The function which generates the choices for the model field is not accessible from the form code unfortunately.)

The best I have come up with so far for is to change the `icon` form field definition to

```
icon = ChoiceField(choices=UserGroup._meta.get_field_by_name('icon')[0].choices, 
                   widget=IconPicker)
```

but this is clunky and I would rather have the choices automatically passed on as in the introspected `ChoiceField` behavior.  (I tried subclassing `ChoiceField` to `IconChoiceField` which was identical but for a default widget of `IconPicker` but Django converts it back to a `TypedChoiceField` with the default `Select` widget because of [this issue](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/9245).)

Is there a way to override the `ChoiceField`'s `widget` attribute while preserving the behavior of inheriting `choices` from the model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the reason you are losing the choices you specified in your model i.e. "sets it to `[]`" **is not "because Django", but because you override the icon field** with the line `icon = models.ChoiceField(widget=IconPicker)`

Please note that if you are using a modelform then it is not necessary to override the widget at init, instead the widget should be specified in the Meta class in the widgets dictionary.

```
class UserGroupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserGroup
        fields = [ 'icon', ]
        widgets = {
            'icon': IconPicker
        }
```

As for overriding the choices you can simply do `self.fields['icon'].choices = UserGroupForm.ICON_CHOICES`, but I don't think you need to override choices in this instance.

Comment: Thanks Tom. I was unaware of the widgets dictionary a year ago.  This is a cleaner solution than mine.

Answer (score 5):

Figured it out.  Just needed a bit of self-reference in `UserGroupForm`'s `__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(UserGroupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['icon'].widget = IconPicker(choices=self.fields['icon'].choices)
```

Comment: This answer is useful since "fields defined declaratively do not draw their attributes like max_length or required from the corresponding model. If you want to maintain the behavior specified in the model, you must set the relevant arguments explicitly when declaring the form field." (quoting django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields).